# RPC interface that works on Windows as well as Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, rpc

I need to write some C/C++ code to be ported to both Windows and Linux, that uses `RPC` (only between processes on the same host, not across the network, so no need for cross-platform calls).

Windows has [MSRPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa378651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Linux has [Sun-RPC](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rpc), but they are not compatible in terms of how you write RPC calls and methods, or even in terms of how you deploy your RPC services.

Does anybody have any clever ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: `#if defined(WIN32) ... #elif defined(__LINUX__) ... #else ... #endif`

Comment: boost.interprocess exists.  I've never tried it.

Comment: boost.interprocess is very low-level. I was hoping for something more at the IDL level where you can declare and call procedures in a natural-looking way. Something like `rpcgen` enabled. I see there is a port of rpcgen to Windows, but it's very old and not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider some [JSONRPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/) ([JSON](http://json.org/) is a textual [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) format, and JSONRPC is an RPC machinery above it)? Or [CORBA](http://www.corba.org/) - which is [Common Object Request Broker Archtecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture), a widely used standard for object-oriented RPC ?

Or probably [POCO libraries](http://pocoproject.org/)? POCO is a cross-platform (both Posix & Windows) framework & library set in C++, it includes network & process & IPC facilities. The [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) cross-platform toolkit also has a core layer providing [QtNetwork](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html) (for network sockets) and [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html) (for managing processes).

Comment: I improved my answer, but I disagree with the comment above by Wim Ombelets. The links I gave are widely used and stable (and the names I gave are googlable). Paraphrasing the description of a widely used library does not bring anything new. And the question itself did (wisely) give only links - without explanations - for *MSRPC* & *Sun-RPC*

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [qjsonrpc](https://bitbucket.org/devonit/qjsonrpc). It's a library developed on top of the Qt library that provides easy-to-use jsonrpc support. It provides both a client and a server, and is supported on linux/osx/windows.

**disclaimer:** I am the author of qjsonrpc, hope you give it a try!